# Topbar notifications don't go away

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, top-bar

I've read the *unread inbox messages* several times.  Despite the fact that there is no new inbox message, the topbar keeps showing a count of *2* for *unread inbox messages*.

This seems new to me, and unless the change was intended (which seems unlikely), it's a bug.

[image]

I can repro it consistently on http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Chrome on Windows? I had this problem a few weeks ago, until I upgraded...

Comment: @Ben Nah! Firefox/Linux.

Comment: Same thing for me (Chromium/Linux). Happens since the end of the maintenance a few minutes ago.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Interestingly, I don't see this problem on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ but only on http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm also seeing this problem, as @0xdeadbeef says, only on Stack Overflow. I have 3 notifications and a +20 in my achievements dialog that keep reappearing when I reload the page.

Comment: I'm seeing this everywhere except this meta & MSE. U&L, Programmers, SF and DBA - same thing.

Comment: Seeing it here on Windows 7 and FF 31ESR. So definitely a problem.

Comment: I think this is after putting site offline today(after 11:00)

Comment: There's some strangeness in the review queues as well. Looks like the site hasn't quite recovered from the maintenance yet.

Comment: Same problem here with FF18 - most annoying.

Comment: Well, I see the opposite. My rep increased (only noticed because it hit a new millennium marker), but I got no notification about the rep event that gave me the 15 points. It does show up in the rep event list in the profile.

Comment: Well, websockets are back but the notifications are still well stuck.

Comment: It's Groundhogs Day with my new rep notification.

Comment: Firefox on Mac OS. Seeing it on all Stack Exchange sites. Clearing caches has not helped so far, nor restarting the browser.

Comment: Same as @RetoKoradi, just had an accepted answer but the notification is a no show - though it is listed in my profile.

Comment: I also received reputation points out of nothing. They are shown in my account overview and in the top bar of the respective community. The StackExchange menu, however, under "Your communities" shows the correct number (Chromium/Linux).

Comment: Ok, so now I'm getting notifications again. They go away when I click on them, but then reappear when I refresh the page, or navigate to a different page. Internet Explorer, Windows 8.1.

Comment: Seeing it across the network...

Comment: I'm not getting any notifications - I just realised I had 3 messages. But just now, randomly I got a rep notification. The drop down is still off by 40+ tho

Comment: Firefox 31 on Windows. Very annoying.

Comment: Link to the MSE bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238155/reputation-notification-shows-up-again-after-refresh

Comment: Same for me. Latest chrome, OS X

Comment: Same thing on android, chrome

Comment: I have got the feeling that this happened after yesterday's failover test. I was online yesterday when it happened.

Comment: Same for me after yesterday failover test. I am using chrome in windows 8.1.

Comment: Same here, seems to be the notifications before yesterday's fail over, doesn't seem to update with the new updates after the fail over either.

Comment: one full day have been gone so far..Still the problem exists...Please do something asap.

Comment: To all programmers around here. I think that all of you have feel this kind of 'heat'. So please stop to whine about it and saying me too is not very helpful. At this point in time I am pretty sure the SO team is well aware of the problem and trying to fix it.

Comment: Same issue here, FF/Ubuntu, on HTTPS. Shows on both SO and MSO. @krupalshah - it's not an urgent bug though, is it?

Comment: @krupalshah: Negative, still seeing it. IOS Safari and [Grazing](http://grazingbrowser.com)

Comment: @tripleee oh yes, sry..it still exists...but now comments are showing...I think SO experts are doing well.

Comment: Maybe I was too quick to comment. Seems to be working for me now.

Comment: its very annoying

Comment: Definitely seeing this problem.  I think it had sorta been there for several days, with the numbers "popping back up" several times, but has gotten more severe since yesterday, to where the numbers never seem to reset.  (I'm on Firefox 31.0.)

Comment: Just a rhetorical question: How long does it take to push a quick sw update to show on the UI that there's a bug?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath 42 years.

Comment: @0xdeadbeef: I'm afraid that could be a quite accurate prediction.

Comment: Happening for me as well.

Comment: Happening to me, too.

Comment: He did it. Cheers @shog9. Notifications are gone!

Comment: I also have the problem of the notifications not going away. Only way i got them to go away was to go from stackoverflow to meta and view the notifications there. But then I get the problem of not getting notifications at all afterward on stackoverflow, until signing out and back in on stackoverflow, and then have to repeat the process to get notifications to go away again.

Comment: Joining the choir of "happening to me, too" voices. My bar's been stuck for the entire day.

Comment: Me too, me too, me too ...

Comment: I lost like 5 reputation out of nowhere. ;(

Comment: I have the same thing.

Comment: I too can reproduce this, at least for the rep change notifications. Here is a screen cap showing the behavior: ![screen capture animation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o9HXh.gif)

Comment: Seems like this should have been fixed by now, its been several days. I mean really how hard is that to fix... probably not very hard.

Comment: The problem seems to have abated somewhat.

Comment: Intermittent for me, I can not purposely reproduce but I've seen it several times. Using UTD Firefox on both Windows 7 and XP.

Answer (score 51):

Meanwhile, we need someone to blame for all this:

[image]

But sadly Shog doesn't know how to fix it :(, so we must wait until someone wakes up.

---

Now, seriously speaking the bug is as follows:

- After reading notifications, they reappear whenever you reload the page.
- Notifications are not shown when you get a message in the inbox until you refresh.
- Reputation gains and badges are not pushed.

That's it.

All browsers affected, anywhere, all users.

Comment: I'm not having an issue...So don't think it's *"all users"*.

Comment: @Lankymart you sure.... *waits 30 seconds for answer*

Comment: Yep, lol. Didn't pop up until I refreshed screen though but that might just be coincidence?? ;-)

Comment: *while everyone is still confused, Shog continues his evil schemes*

Comment: Right confirmed. Indicator only appears if I refresh page manually (had notification through on my phone before it came on the laptop). But clicking the indicator removes it and refreshing the page doesn't bring it back again (unless I have a new notification). Running `Windows 7 x64` - `Google Chrome  36.0.1985.143 m` (latest build).

Comment: Never implement UI changes before gong to bed... It's like throwing dice and passing out before they stop rolling... you're never quite sure what you are going to get :)

Comment: I'm not having an issue.

Comment: Firefox 31 on Mac OS X 10.9.4 is showing me 20 points rep gained persistently on new pages and refreshed pages, even now (close to midnight, US/Pacific time).  It's a trifle irritating.

Comment: Reminds me of this time I was was so eager to quickly code a small change to a live site. It was so small it just couldn't fail...

Comment: Just my 2¢: It works fine on chrome.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ now, but before?

Comment: Is this [Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) referred in your answer?  Looks like he's busy fixing it -- _seen  19 mins ago_.

Comment: I saw this in SeaMonkey (where I have severe lock down on cookies and JavaScript, although StackOverflow is white-listed), but after viewing on a different machine using Firefox, I'm not seeing this behavior. Not sure if that means anything or not.

Answer (score 25):

We had problems with a datacenter test that left our caching layer in a partially broken state.

All issues should now be resolved.

Comment: Good to know that it's been fixed.  It might have been nice if someone left a comment acknowledging the issue while it was broken.

Comment: [The bug report on mSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238155/237685) should probably be [status-completed] too.

Answer (score 2):

There is another behavior that started at about the same time, and may be related:  When one, say, adds a comment, then goes off to another page, then returns to the original page, the comment is not there.  One must somehow refresh the page (I usually click the question title) for it to appear.  And I think I've seen this same behavior for other things, like up/down votes.

Another recent odd behavior is that, when coming to a page where I up/down voted some time ago (days/weeks), very often the colored voting arrow does not show until after several seconds.  Previously the color had appeared instantaneously, to my recollection.

This is on Windows Vista with Firefox 31.0.

Comment: Netscape 60.0??

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 -- It'll always be Netscape to me, and I could have sworn it said 60.0 earlier this morning.

Comment: I've seen this behaviour for ages with Firefox (currently 31.0) on Mac OS X (and other browsers on other platforms, I think — Chrome on Linux; Firefox on Linux)  It only happens if I use the back button to go to a page which I added a comment to, or other similar operation.  It retrieves/reuses the state of the page at the time it was first loaded, rather than the state as changed.  I assume that is the browser avoiding a fetch from the website proper as a refresh fixes it each time.

Comment: I believe this behavior is part of a fix. The hot questions list in the right sidebar used to change across history cycles (navigating away then back would give you a different list). The new behavior fixes that.

Comment: FWIW, I see it on Chrome.