# Review votes ignored, and reviews showing repeatedly

Tags: bug, review-queues

This might be related to the other site problems that came up after the site maintenance earlier today, which are discussed here:

[Topbar notifications don't go away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268957/topbar-notifications-dont-go-away)

Since the symptom of this problem is quite different, I thought I'd report it separately just in case.

What happened repeatedly today is that when I tried to vote in a review queue, the vote did not register. The same page with the same review I had just tried to vote on was redisplayed, as if nothing happened. The post did not show any vote, and my voting statistics did not change.

I saw this in both the Edit and Low Quality queues. It also happened for various kinds of votes, both Approve and Reject/Close.

Sometimes the vote would register after about 10-15 attempts of clicking on the button, while reloading the page several times. Mostly I would just skip to the next review after several failed attempts.