# Is changing answers to community wiki acceptable behaviour?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, community-wiki

I recently received a Necromancer badge, but did not get an increase in reputation.  When I went to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client/9237332#9237332), I found it was a community wiki.  I do not usually make things community wiki, so I checked and discovered  hadi.sh [changed my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9237332/revisions) and the others on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81991/641833) to community wiki.

Questions:

1. Is this correct behavior?
2. Can I remove the community wiki from my answer?  If so, how?
3. Is there a way to prevent other users from changing my answers to community wiki without my permission?

My goal is to understand, so details are appreciated.

Comment: It was likely made CW due to the old behavior of it changing *everything* to CW if there were more than 30 answers.  [Seems like it's been removed now.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/81991/timeline)

Comment: @Makoto Thanks, I did not know about that 30 answers thing.

Comment: @Makoto - Poor George, quietly removes the wiki status here, yet when he adds it... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315696/the-question-to-the-answer-about-branch-prediction-turned-into-community-wiki

Comment: @BradLarson:  I know, right?  I was thinking a bit on that when I made the comment...

Comment: @BradLarson I'll think of it this way: George felt so bad after *yesterday's* incident, that he swiftly corrected this one 5 hours ago;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can ask a moderator to remove the community wiki status from your answer.  Just flag the answer as "other" and request a moderator to convert it to back normal answer.

See the flag link on your answer:

> [image]

source: [Remove community wiki from my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147666/remove-community-wiki-from-my-answer)