# Is there a due process for making an old list-style answer where the OP is not easily available community wiki?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, community-wiki

I recently [flagged an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757908/what-parameters-are-required-to-create-an-add-to-google-calendar-link/23495015#23495015) with a custom flag requesting it to be converted into a community wiki<sup>0</sup> post that was subsequently declined. I have no issues with the decline of the flag nor with the reason that this is not actionable, but that lead me to a question I am not sure we have an answer for:

> Is there any consensus on what the due process is for answers that became / are becoming community effort and the OP is not around anymore to make the answer a community wiki?

If I can be pointed to a duplicate target that already answers the question above it would also be a good solution, but I failed in finding one. While searching, I noticed a couple of questions about similar situations that seem to suggest that in such cases a moderator should be involved (at least when a removal of community wiki status is concerned). Also answers [stopped being autoconverted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits) to wikis long time ago:

- [Is changing answers to community wiki acceptable behaviour?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315772/is-changing-answers-to-community-wiki-acceptable-behaviour)
- [Removal of community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status#) status due process
- The discussion sparked on [making *active* user's answer a CW](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315696/the-question-to-the-answer-about-branch-prediction-turned-into-community-wiki)
- Discussion on [listings to be converted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251665/when-should-old-list-of-x-questions-be-kept-as-wikis) into CWs

---

<sup>0 It should be noted that there is a repo with the description of the parameters a link to which is posted as a comment to the question *and* that the question is closed. One could argue that it could be reposted as a CW and built upon if deemed necessary.</sup>

Comment: I see no problem with leaving it not a CW

Comment: @KevinB - I don't see much of a problem as well - just curios if we have an established process to deal with such cases to refer to.

Comment: Why should it be converted to CW?

Comment: @Dharman - well, because it is becoming a community curated list of parameters (my reasoning when flagging). But I am not arguing that it *should be* converted, I understand the flag being declined. I would like to know if we have a consensus and / or due process for a general case? If the process is "do not at all costs" - this is also a good reference point

Comment: Are you aware that that question is closed and at any moment it may be deleted? I think that the best strategy is to move that information elsewhere.

Comment: @Braiam - yep, I am aware, and that is a valid point of concern (though as far as I know with 58 / 58 score, and this many positively received answers its removal chances are slim). I am not sure why it was closed as off-topic in the first place... But transcends the topic of the question a little. That business with "sort-of-official" API endpoints creeps up a lot (Google Sheets being the most active) - I think it warrants a separate discussion on whether or not these questions are acceptable, should we have canonicals, etc

Comment: There seems to be a github repository where this information is https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/google.md

Comment: @Braiam - yeah, it is even mentioned in comments to the question (see my note) - merit of the Q&A aside, I am curious whether we have any guidelines on how to treat such answers (as I have seen plenty for questions, but pretty much nothing for answers)

Comment: This was one instance of migrating content outside of SE https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295495/792066